What are the criteria that we could use to conclude that an entity is designed?
The famous Paley watchmaker argument for intelligent design, goes, approximately:

If you found a watch, you would conclude that it was designed and did
not come into being through naturalistic processes, because it
contains a complex mechanism which clearly serves a function:
indicating with its hands the passage of time. However, living
biological organisms contain many complex mechanisms which serve
various biological functions which are required to keep the organism
alive. Hence, it makes sense to conclude that biological organisms are
also designed.

I always thought that that is not quite ironclad reasoning, because if I found a watch in the wilderness it would not be the complexity and mechanistic processes that convinced me it was designed, it would be that I can't conceive of any way that the various pieces of a watch could have been fabricated and assembled apart from intelligent beings with hands making them and putting them together. Metallic ores don't refine themselves into pure metals or alloys, and then mold that metal into the shapes of springs and cogs and piece them together. Only intelligent beings do these things. By contrast, biological organisms are self-assembling.
Also, the conclusion is skewed by the fact that we know what a watch is for. If we did encounter some artificial artefact but could not determine its purpose, then we might not be so certain that it had been designed. One can imagine that if stone age people found a watch, they might struggle to conclude whether it was an artefact or whether it had occurred through some naturalistic process, because they would not be able to conceive what it could possibly be for.
So my question is, what criteria could we use to determine whether some object showed evidence of design, if it clearly and obviously was not of human origin. For example, if we encountered a hollow metallic cylinder in orbit around Jupiter that was 2km in length, would we be justified in concluding definitively that it had been designed and fabricated by intelligent beings, or would we need to allow for the possibility that it had occurred through some unknown naturalistic process? Or, considering another possibility, if we encountered self-reproducing machines such as Vonn Neuman probes made by an intelligent alien species, could we distinguish them from an unknown form of organic life?

Related: Even in an infinite multiverse, would observing a Dyson sphere in outer space be strong evidence of design?

Similar questions: Is there a general theory of intelligence and design that would allow us to detect the presence of design in an object based solely on its properties?, If we encounter what appears to be an advanced extraterrestrial technological device, would the claim that it was designed be falsifiable?,

There is no reason, ever, to posit a designer (especially a supernatural one) if He is invisible and there is no means by which His design process can be observed or tested. It is impossible to distinguish between an invisible entity working behind the scenes and no entity working behind the scenes, and per Occam’s razor, there are a great many reasons to prefer the latter.

@Syed the OP seems to be suggesting that hypotheses like "there do not exist alien designers" is falsifiable, because it makes predictions like "no observations of enormous spaceships orbiting extra-solar planets."  If we were to observe such a spaceship, then this may reasonably falsify our hypothesis that there did not exist such designers.

@Him It only makes sense to posit designers if the designer can itself be created from simpler processes. Perhaps aliens might fit into this category if they were created from evolutionary processes (and even this is debatable) but God does not. Hence it never makes sense to posit a God since His complexity in traditional theism is uncaused. If philosophers realized this, they’d save centuries of mental effort

@Syed "Pehaps aliens might fit... never makes sense to posit a God" - The difference is not as obvious, I think, as you suggest. Arthur C Clarke says that "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic."  If you specifically mean the Abrahamic God: Do you assert that "the God of Abraham does not exist" is unfalsifiable?  I think you may be conflating the hypothesis of the OP's question with its negation.

@Syed although I tagged the post with intelligent-design, and mentioned watchmakers, I wasn't specifically asking about supernatural or invisible designers.

@Syed, Occam's razor favors the least incredible series of coincidences.

The best criterion to conclude that an entity is designed is to show its designer.
But unfortunately it is just the absence of a designer which starts the controversy. Hence we only have hypotheses about the origin.  And one has to consider and to weight the arguments which speak for the different types of explanation.
IMO this must be done separately for each controversial case. I do not know a general criterion which settles all cases.

One criterion that I would find pretty convincing is if it came with a manual.
Though, there is of course always the off chance that the manual is actually an alien itself...

Well, since most software no longer comes with a manual, this lines up with my feeling that most software is no longer designed, but is instead subjected to random variation (A/B testing), and then the variations that do best (as measured by # of users and amount of VC $$) survive (continue to be supported).

@JonathanZ Throw it at the wall and see what sticks...

I'm just realizing that if the absence of evidence has lead to me not believing in the existence of any god, then I might not believe in computer programmers either.

@JonathanZ All organically grown by object oriented gardening...

Jo is right: identifying the designer would be the best proof for any design. In the absence of the designer herself, one could try and find her signature or stamp on the designed item. It's usually at the bottom. :-)
For instance, this answer was designed by little me, and you can find my avatar at the bottom as proof.

Well, another comment suggested that a working watch could have been assembled by a supernova so it seems I should also allow for the possibility that your post, along with your user profile and avatar, resulted from random packets caused by a rare and spontaneous glitch in a router somewhere.....

@Batperson Well then, you will be thrown into eternal flames after you die. That's the price to pay to doubt my existence... ;-)

Some might consider DNA to be a form of signature...  (what are you looking for, "made by God®"?!)

DNA is just the hard-drive. Somewhere on this hard-drive, there could conceivably be some [explanatory text from the programmer] encoded in natural godly language.

@Olivier5 your claim seems to have mutated from the mundane to the extraordinary.

@Batperson Mundane, moi?

We must know that it is not possible for it to come about naturally on a physical level.
One flaw in the argument for that definition of design is how you identify the purpose of an object.

If you found a watch, you would conclude that it was designed and did not come into being through naturalistic processes, because it contains a complex mechanism which clearly serves a function: indicating with its hands the passage of time. However, living biological organisms contain many complex mechanisms which serve various biological functions which are required to keep the organism alive. Hence, it makes sense to conclude that biological organisms are also designed.

How does an alien, whose civilization never developed any such timekeeping methods, know what a watch is? To an unenlightened alien, and indeed to the Universe sans human observer, the watch just is what it is, a system with the slightly-special property of periodic motion.
Another, more major issue: it is not actually impossible for a watch to come into existence ex nihilo. It is extremely unlikely, but it is not impossible: in a cloud of gas somewhere out there, shortly after a supernova synthesized all the heavy elements required, a few trillion/quadrillion/quintillion atoms could just so happen to fly together in a way that instantly causes the creation of a human watch. No, this will not likely be observed in the span of human civilization’s existence, but it is also certainly not impossible. Consider also the very idea of the Boltzmann brain.
Additionally, I would say that the structures of the biological organism are also not “designed”. Aside from there being countless practically-useless components and effects that can cause us to just spontaneously convulse and die when something goes slightly wrong, we can trace back through genetics the predecessors of humans back to the earlier forms of life on the Earth, and we can do this for other species as well. This suggests, to me and some others at least, that the complexities of life are capable of emerging gradually “on their own”. Indeed it is possible for there to have been a designer - there is in every conceivable circumstance - but it seems that it is not required to produce what is observed.
All that is to say that this definition of “designed” is probably not truly sufficient for our purposes: a watch can come into existence from nothing and life can too seem to evolve from much-simpler organisms - you and I agree on this. The issue that presents itself is that by the Boltzmann brain logic any entity, designed or not, can appear to be designed and can still have arrived in reality from nothing but random chance, and this is except by probabilistic approximation indistinguishable from the entity having been designed and built. For an entity to have been designed and built, the most convincing evidence one could provide is of course some infallible record of the process of design and construction; irrespective of who the designer actually was, if it could be shown that some external force is strictly required to bring about the object’s existence, then it would clearly have had to have been designed and built.
Example of what would be clearly designed
One such example would be a satellite stably orbiting a black hole exactly-on the last photon sphere. In this case, it would be impossible, physically speaking, for a satellite to arrive at that exact position and trajectory by chance; any further in, and it would fall towards the event horizon, and any further out, and it wouldn’t be on such a stable orbit, and in order for it to be in its orbit it had to produce retrograde impulse at periapsis. Simple asteroid satellites might be able to spontaneously change their orbits by outgassing or the like, but none can provide the instantaneous impulse required to maneuver into such a position. As such, if we observed such an object, we could safely conclude that some designer placed it there.
Could this still happen by random chance? No, and thus this scenario was designed. A simple asteroid which somehow randomly came about with a pseudo-engine setup inside itself, fueled by pressurized gas, still could not physically produce enough thrust to maneuver into this position because doing so requires very high thrust and thus very high engine temperatures and pressures, which are only withstandable by alloys that require massive industrial processes to create, and which starkly do not exist anywhere in nature. Could a factory capable of producing this alloy and even a starship to get into low orbit of a black hole spawn ex nihilo? Yes, but it would need to happen in a place where the available resources are nearby, which is limited to places near stars like planets and moons and asteroids - places where, if we found such a factory, we would instead conclude that a nearby civilization built it, in which case that civilization is the designer (in fact if the factory somehow appeared in the void we could just as well call it a designer, even if it had no consciousness). In other words, in this scenario,  the situation is clearly designed and that is the conclusion that we should make, since the situation necessarily was orchestrated by something or someone.

I'm not sure that your example of a satellite orbiting a black hole is "clearly designed": if we are going to admit infinitesimal possibilities such as a watch being assembled through naturalistic processes in a supernova, it seems that anything could including a satellite capable of manoeuvering itself into orbit around a black hole, made of whatever alloys you like! It's simply a a case of multiple improbabilities instead of only 1.

Having done the orbital calculations for fun, let me tell you - getting a satellite into that orbit requires that you perform multiple burns with an intentionally-designed vehicle. If any parameter is off at all, it won’t work. A watch can have a gear 1/100th of a cm too big and work mostly fine, or have the exterior a bit malformed. This specific case was designed (by me) so that every measurement involved must be exact, and randomly picking out any exact number from any subset of the reals happens with probability 0.

Given an infinite multiverse, or a single universe instantiating an infinite number of times, or an infinite number of asteroids supernovas and black holes....... but still, some things we should just classify as impossible even if in principle there is a non-zero probability of them occurring.

In philosophy, designing entities relies on conceptual clarity, internal coherence, and compatibility with the broader philosophical framework. Each entity must be examined ontologically, epistemologically, and, at times, ethically to determine its precise role and significance.

As Jo mentioned, the only sure way to know that something is designed is to literally observe the designer actually designing it. In every single case of a successful design inference, we have always had direct or indirect access to the actual designers designing the things in question, such as the factories that create watches.
Without this, an undesigned process cannot be ruled out and might even be preferred since a new, unobserved designer only begs the question of what designed it. And if that designer is even more complex than the entity in question, why posit it?
The traditional notion of a designer is one who is All Powerful, All Knowing, etc. And despite claims to the contrary, this deity is as complex as one can get. Just think about it. If you came across an unknown object, then an All Powerful God could create that object and an infinite amount of other things. How can this be a simpler explanation than merely positing that an undesigned process created that thing?
Positing designers, especially all powerful ones, leads nowhere despite the temptation.

In short, do you disagree with this answer?

It depends on the type of designer posited. If it is God, then God is more complex than a Dyson sphere. So a Dyson sphere wouldn’t be evidence of god (but maybe some alien civilization that evolved through simpler processes).

But wouldn't that contradict your answer here? Because you have never observed an alien civilization, let alone an alien civilization designing a Dyson sphere, let alone abiogenesis followed by evolution followed by an alien civilization that designs Dyson spheres. Have you ever observed that?

@user80226 that’s why I said maybe. I’m not convinced that evolution is probable enough such that other very intelligent lifeforms can emerge, so I’m not sure if a Dyson sphere forming naturally is any more likely than other intelligent life forms emerging (we also still don’t understand how life started).
